# Representing a nonlinear elliptic PDE as an energy minimization problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I need to solve a PDE in 2D representing a (time-independent) nonlinear diffusion process. The unknown function is $\phi(x,y)$ and its gradients create fluxes $\vec J$ through a nonlinear relation:
$$\vec J = (\phi+h)^\alpha\frac{\vec\nabla\phi}{\sqrt{|\vec \nabla\phi|}} \ .$$
The PDE to be solved (representing steady-state flow) is 
$$
\operatorname{div}\vec J = \partial_x J_x+\partial_y J_y =0 \ .
$$
$h(x,y)$ is a given function and the values of $\phi$ are known on the boundary of the domain (Dirichlet problem).

For various reasons, both numerical and analytic, I want to represent the problem as an energy-minimization problem. That is, to find a functional $\mathcal{L}(\phi, \vec\nabla\phi)$ whose minimizer is a solution to the PDE (or yet in other words: a functional whose Euler-Lagrange equation is the PDE).

Is there a general way to do this, or to prove that it is impossible? Without the $(\phi+h)^\alpha$ term I can easily guess the functional, but I couldn't make it work with it.

Answer (score 5):

As already said by Kosh, you are trying to solve an *inverse problem in the calculus of variation*: in its classical formulation, given a system of PDE, the problem consists in *finding a functional whose Euler-Lagrange equations are exactly the given PDE(s)*.
 
To my knowledge, a necessary and sufficient condition for a system of PDE (jointly with its boundary/Cauchy conditions) to be the Euler-Lagrange equation(s) of a Lagrangian functional (meaning  functional which is the integral of a function whose arguments, apart from a "independent" variable $\mathbf{x}$, are the unknown function $\phi$ and its lower order derivatives) is still unknown.
However, it is possible to approach the problem from a more general yet concrete point of view: consider a general operator 
$$
\phi\mapsto\mathsf{N}(\phi)(\mathbf x)-f(\mathbf{x}),\label{op}\tag{OP}
$$ 
where

- $\mathsf N$ is a linear or nonlinear  operator (possibly your differential operator, an integral operator, a system of PDEs etc.),
- $\phi\in\operatorname{Dom}(\mathsf N)$, the domain of $\mathsf N$ in an appropriate function space, and
- $f\in\operatorname{Range}(\mathsf N)$ the range of $\mathsf N$ again in an appropriate function space.

The kernel of this operator is characterized by the following equation

$$
\mathsf N(\phi)(\mathbf x)=f(\mathbf{x}).\label{1}\tag{1}
$$ 
If there exists a general functional $F$ such that its [functional derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives) vanish on the set of solution(s) of \eqref{1}, i.e. 
$$
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}F(\phi+\varepsilon\psi)\right|_{\varepsilon =0}\!\!\!=0\;\;\,\forall\psi \in \operatorname{Dom}(\mathsf N)\iff \phi(\mathbf x)\text{ is a solution of \eqref{1},}\label{gvf}\tag{GVF}
$$
the problem \eqref{1} is said to admit an *extended variational formulation* and the operator \eqref{op} is said to be a *potential operator* (or *conservative operator* according to [2] §3 p. 152).
Enzo Tonti (see [1], chapter III §11.1 p. 94 and chapter IV §§17.1-17.4, pp. 168-162 and the recent paper [2] or [the Author's web site](http://www.discretephysics.org/en/papers/), where a brief survey of the result is given) proved that, under fairly general conditions, a such a functional $F$ always exists. Precisely, Tonti's theorem says that *every linear / nonlinear problem \eqref{1}, provided some natural hypotheses are assumed, admits an extended variational formulation*. The proof is constructive in that it shows that it is possible to explicitly construct a compact self-adjoint invertible linear operator $\mathsf K$ such that the functional
$$
F(\phi)=\int\limits_\Omega \mathsf N(\phi)\mathsf K\big(\mathsf N(\phi)-f\big)\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
satisfies \eqref{gvf}: moreover, if $\mathsf{K}$ is also a *positive definite operator* (i.e. $\langle v, \mathsf{K}v\rangle>0$ for all functions $v\in \operatorname{Dom}(\mathsf K)$ such that $v\not\equiv 0$), the the solutions of \eqref{1} are the minimum points of the functional \eqref{2} ([2] §4 theorem 2 pp. 155-156). Thus applying the techniques described in [1] and [2] you can surely find variational formulation for your problem, even if it cannot be expressed as the Euler-Lagrange equation(s) of an appropriate energy functional.

**Notes**

- When $\phi, f$ belong to function spaces on sufficiently regular domains $\Omega$, then the Green's operator associated to the Green's function for a any symmetric linear PDE on $\Omega$ can be chosen as the needed $\mathsf{K}$ operator. When $\Omega$ is not regular, there are nevertheless other possible choices: some of them are described in §5, pp. 156-161 of [2].
- The analytical approach to the inverse problem of the calculus of variations is perhaps comprehensively described in the wonderful monograph [1], which is however up to date up to 1989: on the other hand [2] surveys nicely the theory of potential operator up to the more recent development due to the Author.
- In remark 17.1 of [1] chapter IV, §17.2 pp. 171-172, Filippov gives a brief but very interesting survey on the conditions of potentiality for a nonlinear differential operator (ordinary or partial): perhaps, if something more tailored to the form of a given equation respect to \eqref{2} is needed, it would be worth to have a look at the references cited there.

**References**

[1] Filippov, Vladimir Mikhailovich, *[Variational principles for nonpotential operators](https://www.ams.org/books/mmono/077/)*. With an appendix by the author and V. M. Savchin, Transl. from the Russian by J. R. Schulenberger. Transl. ed. by Ben Silver, Translations of Mathematical Monographs, 77. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). pp. xiii+239 (1989), ISBN: 0-8218-4529-2. [MR1013998](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1013998), [ZBL0682.35006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0682.35006).

[2] Tonti, Enzo, "[Extended variational formulation](http://www.discretephysics.org/DEPOSITO/Tonti-russi.pdf)", Vestnik Rossiĭskogo Universiteta Druzhby Narodov, Seriya Matematika 2, No. 2, 148-162 (1995). [ZBL0965.35036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0965.35036).

Answer (score 4):

In general, the problem can be complicated because some nonlinearities arise as Lagrange multipliers. Therefore, an energy functional (whose Euler-Lagrange equations coincide with the nonlinear PDE) can exist provided that some constraints to the energy functional are imposed.

Anyhow, the general problem is called *The Inverse Problem of the Calculus of Variations*.
There is a quite recent book on that. You can take a look at it.

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789462391086