# Pointwise functional derivative as partial derivative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Suppose $x_{1},...,x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ are fixed and $f: \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d}) \to \mathbb{C}$ is given by: 
$$ f(\phi) = e^{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\phi(x_{j})}$$
with $\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$. I'd like to know if there is any kind of derivative whose derivative of $f$ would be:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}e^{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\phi(x_{j})}$$
In other words, it would be as if we're considering partial derivatives $\partial/\partial \phi(x_{j})$, $j=1,...,n$, such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi(x_{j})} e^{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\phi(x_{j})} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}e^{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\phi(x_{j})}.$$
Is there a way to define such objects in a precise/rigorous way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [functional derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives/349584#349584) is what you need:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} &\triangleq \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon} f(\phi+\varepsilon\varphi)\right|_{\varepsilon=0} = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}e^{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}[\phi(x_{j})+\varepsilon\varphi(x_i)]}\right|_{\varepsilon=0}\\
& =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\varphi(x_j)e^{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\phi(x_{j})}
\end{split}
$$
and choosing $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\Bbb R^d)$ such that $\varphi(x_j)=1$ for all $j=1,\ldots,n$ does the Job.

**Notes**

- **The choice of the variation $\varphi$.** Since $\{x_j: j=1,\ldots,n\}\subsetneq\Bbb R^d$, the choice of a suitable $\varphi(x)$ is always possible and moreover, you could extend the above formula even to the case  $j\in\Bbb N_+=\Bbb N\setminus \{0\}$, provided the indexed (numerable) family of points $\{x_j\}_{j\in\Bbb N_+}$ is contained in a suitable bounded set $M\subsetneq\Bbb R^d$: in all these cases, you can choose a sufficiently large compact set $K\Supset M$ and mollify its characteristic function by the heat kernel (if you do not want a compactly supported function), i.e.
  $$
  \varphi(x)=\varphi(x,t)=\int\limits_K \mathscr{K}(x-y, t)\,\mathrm{d}y
  $$
  where
  $$
  \mathscr{K}(x, t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(4\pi t)^d}}e^{-\dfrac{\langle x,x\rangle}{4t}}.
  $$
- **On the domain of definition of $f$(and thus again on $\varphi$)**. As user131781 noted in the comments, $f$ is defined on a much wider space than the "sole" $\mathcal{S}(\Bbb R^d)$. Its domain is at least the whole $\mathcal{E}(\Bbb R^d)\equiv C^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$, thus also *the functional derivative $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\phi}}$ is defined and meaningful  for every $\varphi\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$* and the choice $\varphi(x) \equiv 1$ is perfectly licit. However, the choices of $\varphi$ described above show that the very same solution holds in more stricter spaces where, perhaps by unstated context consideration, the functional $\varphi$ is bounded to act.

Comment: Does $\varphi = 1 \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$?

Comment: No, however you can use a function $\varphi(x)$ such that $\varphi(x_j)=1$ for all $j=1,\ldots, n$. I'll clarify this point in the answer.

Comment: I think I got it! Just one more thing. Once $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ are fixed, another approach would be to find functions $\varphi_{j} \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ such that $\varphi_{j}(x_{j}) = 1$ and $\varphi_{j}(x_{k}) = 0$ for $k\neq j$ right? Then I would have $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f(\phi)}{\partial\varphi_{j}(x)} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}f(\phi)$.

Comment: The problem is how to find these functions

Comment: @MathMath no, it is not a problem: choose the standard mollifier $$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/(1-|x|^2)}/I_n& \text{ if } |x| < 1\\ 0& \text{ if } |x|\geq 1\end{cases}$$ where $I_n$ is the standard normalizing factor. Then putting $$\epsilon=\frac{1}{10}\sup_\overset{\displaystyle{i,j =1,\ldots,n}}{\displaystyle{ i\neq j}}|x_j-x_i|,$$ you can create the sought for function as a sum of the functions $$\varphi^\epsilon_j(x)=\varphi_j(x,\epsilon) =\epsilon^{-d}\varphi\left(\frac{x-x_j}{\epsilon}\right), \quad j=1,\ldots, n.$$

Comment: Great! You helped me so much! Thanks!

Comment: I think I got another example of such functions. Take your $\varphi$ with $I_{n} = e$, so that $\varphi(0) = 1$. Then $\mbox{supp} \varphi \subset \bar{B}_{1}(0)$ (the closed ball centered at zero and radius 1). Take $\epsilon_{j} := \frac{1}{10}\min_{j} |x_{i}-x_{j}|$ and define $\psi_{j}(x) := \varphi\bigg{(}\frac{x-x_{j}}{\epsilon_{j}}\bigg{)}$. Then $\psi_{j}(x_{j}) = \varphi(0) = 1$, $\psi(x_{i}) = 0$ if $i \neq j$ because $\mbox{supp} \psi_{j} \subset \bar{B}_{\epsilon_{j}}(x_{j})$ and $\varphi$ is $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: @MathMath nice example. By the way, I note that you correctly deleted the $varepsilon^{-d}$ term: I should have done the same in my post above.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for the help and assistance!

Comment: I hope it is not rude to say that this answer, while correct, is much too complicated.  The situation is that you have a continuous linear functional on a lcs (a linear combination of $\delta$-distributions) composed with the one dimensional smooth  exponential function. Both of these are clearly differentiable and hence so is their composition whose derivative can then be calculated by the chain  rule.  The use of mollifiers is spurious since  this functional is continuous on much larger spaces (a more rigorous condition) which contain $1$,  for example, the continuous functions.

Comment: Of course, once you know that it is differentiable in this much stronger sense, it is perfectly legitimate to compute it as a directional derivative as in the original answer (without the further considerations).

Comment: @user131781 I understand your point: it is simple to see that $f(\varphi)$ is defined on the whole $\mathcal{E}(\Bbb R^d)\equiv C^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$, thus I can readily define the functional derivative in a wider, stronger sense on such spaces (where $1$ is an admissible variation). I'll add a note on your comment to the answer.  However, I bounded myself to $\mathcal{S}(\Bbb R^d)$ since we may be right in saying that the domain of definition of $f$ is wider, but MathMath may be bounded to consider  this more restrict space by unstated context considerations