# Fréchet derivative of evaluation-like functional (multivariate)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, calculus-of-variations, differential-calculus, functional-calculus

I'm fairly new to functional calculus but and posting here since the question seems more appropriate than for MSE.  When coming across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463116/frechet-derivative-of-evaluation-function) I could not help but wonder the following.

Let $H$ be the reproducing-kernel Hilbert space obtained by completing the set of all $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ with finite norm finite:
$$
\|f(x)\|_H:= \|f(0)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m} + \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \|(\nabla f)(x)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m} e^{-\|x\|} dx.
$$

If $w:C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is the functional
$$
(f,x) \mapsto \|f(x)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m},
$$
what is its Fréchet derivative?  Thinking analogously to the linked post and appealing to the chain-rule for Fréchet derivatives, I would guess it is
$$
Dw(f,x) (g,y)= \frac1{\|g(x)+J_f(y)\|}\left(g(x) + (J_f)(y)\right).
$$
However, I don't know how to show more than this (if even it is a correct ansatz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general procedure for the identification of a Fréchet derivative is the following

1. Calculate the [functional derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives) of the given functional, then
2. verify its linearity and
3. verify its continuity respect to the topology that is considered on the domain of the given functional i.e., for a Banach or Hilbert space topology, verify that the norm of the derivative does not depend on the structure of the variation but only on its size (norm).

The functional $w$ is defined on a vector space structure defined on $C^1(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m)\times \Bbb R^n$, since we should be able to give a meaning to the word "[linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678005/what-does-it-mean-for-something-to-be-linear)", and the topology considered on this vector space is the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) between the Banach space topology on $\Bbb R^n$ and the topology by $H$ on $C^1(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m)$: following the above list we have
$$
\begin{split}
Dw\big[(f,x)\big]\big((g,y)\big) & \triangleq \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}w\big[(f,x)+\varepsilon(g,y)\big]\bigg{|}_{\varepsilon = 0}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}w\big[(f+\varepsilon g, x+\varepsilon y)\big]\bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}\big\|f(x+\varepsilon y)+\varepsilon g(x+\varepsilon y)\big\|\bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0}\\
&=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m \Big(f_i(x+\varepsilon y)+\varepsilon g_i(x+\varepsilon y)\Big)^2\bigg]^\frac{1}{2}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}{\big\|f(x+\varepsilon y)+\varepsilon g(x+\varepsilon y)\big\|}^{-1} \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m \Big(f_i(x+\varepsilon y)+\varepsilon g_i(x+\varepsilon y)\Big)^2\bigg]\right|_{\varepsilon = 0}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}{\big\|f(x+\varepsilon y)+\varepsilon g(x+\varepsilon y)\big\|}^{-1}\\
&\qquad\cdot \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m  f_i^2(x+\varepsilon y)+ 2\varepsilon f_i(x+\varepsilon y)g_i(x+\varepsilon y) +\varepsilon^2 g_i^2(x+\varepsilon y)\bigg]\right|_{\varepsilon = 0}\\
&={\big\|f(x+\varepsilon y)+\varepsilon g(x+\varepsilon y)\big\|}^{-1}\\
&\qquad\cdot \bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m  \langle\nabla f_i(x+\varepsilon y),y\rangle+  f_i(x+\varepsilon y)g_i(x+\varepsilon y) \\ 
&\qquad\qquad +\varepsilon\langle\nabla f_i(x+\varepsilon y),y\rangle g(x+\varepsilon y) +\varepsilon f_i(x+\varepsilon y) \langle \nabla g_i(x+\varepsilon y),y\rangle \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad  + \varepsilon g_i^2(x+\varepsilon y)
+ \left.\varepsilon^2 g_i(x+\varepsilon y)\langle \nabla g_i(x+\varepsilon y),y\rangle\bigg]\right|_{\varepsilon = 0}\\
&={\big\|f(x)\big\|}^{-1}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m  \langle\nabla f_i(x),y\rangle
+f_i(x)g_i(x)\bigg]=\frac{\langle 1, \mathbf{J}_f(x)y\rangle+\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle }{\big\|f(x)\big\|}
\end{split}
$$
Thus, apart from errors, we have done step 1 and checked the linearity as required by step 2. Regarding step 3, *we see that that if*
$$
\|f(x)\|>0 \iff f(x)\neq 0
$$
for the given $x\in\Bbb R^n$, then the functional derivative norm depend only on the value $\|g(x)\|_H+\|y\|_{\Bbb R^n}$ and not on the structure of the element $(g,y)$. Thus the functional derivative of $w$ is a Fréchet derivative.

Comment: Great answer Daniele.  May I ask, have you ever come across this space/ is it a well-studied object?

Comment: Thank you, @AnnieLeKatsu. Regarding the linear product space $C^1(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m)\times\Bbb R^n$ I am not aware of other uses and I haven’t seen it used in the literature. It’s a very particular space since it is the product between a infinite dimensional Hilbert space and a finite dimensional one, and I constructed (or better guessed)the structure of its topology from the one you gave to $C^1$ and the standard  $\Bbb R^n$ one.

Comment: Oh I meant $C^1$ with topology induced by the inner product I provided.

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu the answer is still no: however, the inner product you provided reminds me of (as it is very similar to) the one defined on the [Segal-Bargmann space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%E2%80%93Bargmann_space), which is a Hilbert space of entire functions and has recently been investigated extensively by [Brian C. Hall](https://math.nd.edu/people/faculty/brian-c-hall/).

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu, after thinking a bit, I noticed that the structure of Hilbert space you provided on $C^1(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m)$ is quite common: indeed it is a weighted Hilbert space with weight $\|x\|$. This kind of structure was used also by Hörmander for the solution of the $\bar\partial$-equation, therefore is quite "popular": by googling that name, you'll probably find a lot of information on spaces closer to the one you use than Segal-Bargmann ones I associated by analogy.

Comment: Ah this is nice, you mean googling Hörmander spaces?  I've only ofund some russian texts...

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu, better "Weighted Hilbert space". In general Hörmander spaces are (weighted) Hilbert spaces only if their associated Lebesgue space is $L^2$: otherwise they are only Banach. By googling "Weighted Hilbert space" you should be able to choose from a wide range of constructions and find what you need.

Comment: How much would it change if $n=m$ and we evalue $f\circ f$ instead of $f$ at x?  We only switch $J_f$ for $J_{f\circ f}?$

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu I suspect it is not so: as a matter of fact $$ (f+\varepsilon g)\circ (f +\varepsilon g)\neq f\circ f+\varepsilon g\circ g.$$ However, despite the presumably higher complexity of calculations, the same method for the calculation of functional derivative is applicable. Just the computations are more tedious.