# Euler-Lagrange equation for a functional

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, definitions, fractional-calculus

What does it mean that the equation:
$$ \text{div}_{x,y}(y^a\nabla_{x,y}u)=0,\quad \text{in }\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty),$$
is the Euler-Lagrange equation for the functional:
$$ J(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,\infty)}y^a|\nabla_{x,y}u(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy?$$
Morover there exist a Banach space on which is defined $J$?
I find this terminology in ["An extension problem related to the fractional Laplacian"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608640.pdf) by Caffarelli-Silvestre at page 2.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the [functional derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives) of $J(u)$ is zero (i.e. $J(u)$ has $u$ as a stationary point) if the function $u$ solves the given divergence form PDE, i.e.
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\divg}{\mathrm{div}} \DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{\nabla}
\bigg{[}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\epsilon}J(u+\epsilon \varphi)\bigg{]}_{\epsilon = 0} =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{J(u+\epsilon \varphi)-J(u)}{\epsilon} =  0\iff\divg_{x,y} \big(y^a \grad_{x,y} u\big)=0
$$
for all test function $\varphi\in C^1_c(\Bbb R^n\times [0,+\infty)\big)$, where
$$
\bigg{[}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\epsilon}J(u+\epsilon \varphi)\bigg{]}_{\epsilon = 0} = 2\int\limits_{\Bbb R^n \times [0,+\infty)} \!\!\!\!\! y^a\langle\grad_{x,y}u(x,y), \grad_{x,y}\varphi(x,y)\rangle\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\label{1}\tag{FD}
$$
The given PDE is equivalent to the vanishing of the functional (as a matter of fact, Gâteaux or Frechet) derivative \eqref{1}, provided $u$ is $C^2$-smooth, has a sufficiently smooth boundary value on $y=0$, as can be seen by applying [Du Boys-Reymond's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations): this is classically known and due to Euler and Lagrange, and thus PDEs that come as necessary conditions for the vanishing of the functional derivative of a given (integral) functional are called "Euler-Lagrange equations" of the given functional.

**Edit following the comments**

As a follow-up of the discussion started on comments on how to prove the uniqueness of the solution of the following Dirichlet problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\divg_{x,y} \big(y^a \grad_{x,y} u\big)=0\\
u|_{y=0}=u_0\in \mathscr{S}(\Bbb R^n)
\end{cases}\label{2}\tag{1}
$$
where $\mathscr{S}(\Bbb R^n)$ is the ordinary Schwarz space, it may be noted that the functional $J(u)$ could be defined naturally on the following weighted Sobolev space
$$
\begin{split}
H^1_{y^a}\big(\Bbb R^n\times [0,+\infty)\big) & \equiv W^{1,2}_{y^a} \big(\Bbb R^n\times [0,+\infty)\big) \\
& \triangleq\Big\{u\in L^2\big(\Bbb R^n\times [0,+\infty)\big) : \|u_{0}\|_{L^2(\Bbb R^n)} + J(u) < +\infty\Big\} \\
\end{split}
$$
(here we have put $u_0=u_{y=0}$ in order to simplify the notation) which is naturally Hilbert when equipped with the following inner product
$$
\langle u , v \rangle_{H^1_{y^a}}= \langle u_0 , v_0 \rangle_{L^2(\Bbb R^n)} +\int\limits_{\Bbb R^n \times [0,+\infty)} \!\!\!\!\! y^a\langle\grad_{x,y}u(x,y), \grad_{x,y}v(x,y)\rangle\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
(proving the completeness of this space does not seem to be too difficult). Using this Hilbert space for studying problem \eqref{2} seems to be quite natural, since

- $\mathscr{S}(\Bbb R^n)\subsetneq L^2(\Bbb R^n)$ so it is possible to efficiently deal with the boundary condition, and
- $C_c^\infty(\Bbb R^n)\times C_c^\infty\big( \mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty)\big)$ is dense in $H^1_{y^a}$ as this spaces explicitly deals with boundary conditions and thus
- with the Hilbert space structure and the density of it is possible to use well known methods to prove existence and uniqueness of solution $u$.

Comment: the weighted $W^1_2$ Sobolev space that you have defined is an Hilbert space ? The weighted $L^2$ norm of gradient it seems no to be a norm in $W^1_2$. Moreover, the smooth function with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty)$ is dense in $W^1_2$? 
Moreover if $u\not\in W^1_2$, $u$ can’t be a critical point of $J$.

Comment: @inoc I apologize for I have put a typo: it should be $u\in L^2(\Bbb R\times [0,+\infty)$. The norm in this Sobolev space should be defined as $$ \|u\|_{W^1_2(g)} = \|u\|_{L^2} + \int\limits_{\Bbb R^n \times [0,+\infty)} \!\!\!\!\!\!g(x,y)|\nabla_{x,y}u(x,y)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x$$ as is it customary in (old?) presentations of the theory of Sobolev spaces, and this is a norm (provided the weight function $g$  1s positive on $\Bbb R^n\times [0,+\infty)$).

Comment: $C_c^\infty( \mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty))$ is dense in $W_2^1$?

Comment: As for your other questions, $C_c^1({\Bbb R^n \times [0,+\infty)})$ is not dense in $W_2^1(g)$ since it cannot approximate the boundary values of $u\in W_2^1(g)$. However, density is not required for the Du Bois-Reymond's lemma to hold: indeed it is mandatory that the test functions $\varphi$ vanish on the boundary of the given domain, also for [other reasons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613861/derive-the-euler-lagrange-equation-for-a-functional-a-single-variable-with-highe/2623511#2623511) pertaining to the boundary values you expect from $u$.

Comment: @inoc Finally, you are also right saying $u\notin W_2^1$ implies $u$ can't be a critical point of $J$ despite being a solution of the given PDE: this is also true for Laplace's equation $\Delta u=0$. There are harmonic functions that are continuous on the boundary of their domain of definition without being critical point of the associated [Dirichlet functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_energy), as the Prym-Hadamard phenomenon shows us: however, the laplacian **is nevertheless** the Euler-Lagrange equation of the Dirichlet functional.

Comment: But so, let $u$ the function in Caffarelli Silvestre that solves the problem pointwise, $u\not\in W^1_2$ implies that $u$ is not a critical point. So i don’t have a variational formulation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117345/discussion-between-daniele-tampieri-and-inoc).

Comment: @inoc I apologize for the later, but I've come up with the idea exposed above. I hope it will help you and, as is it customary to say during this period, I wish you a Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year.