# Gelfand "Calculus of Variation" 1.7 question on definition and purpose of variational derivative

Tags: calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

In Gelfand *Calculus of Variation*, chapter 1.7, the *variational derivative* is defined as:

> $$\left.\frac{\partial J}{\partial y}\right|_{x = x_0} = \lim_{\Delta\sigma \rightarrow 0}\frac{J[y+h]-J[y]}{\Delta\sigma},$$ where $h(x)$ is different from zero only in the neighborhood of $x_0$. Also $\Delta\sigma$ is the area lying between the curve $h(x)$ and the x-axis, and $\Delta\sigma$ goes to zero in such a way that both $\max|h(x)|$ and the length of the interval in which $h(x)$ is non-vanishing goes to zero

I wonder if there exist a more precise statement for this definition and if there is any characterization of when such a derivative exist. Also, is there any relation between the *variational derivative* and the *variation (or differential)* of a functional defined in Gelfand chapter 1.3.2.

Moreover, what is the purpose of this definition?

Comment: This is the original definition of "Functional derivative" given by Vito Volterra: I have some more comments to add, and I'll do this later.

Comment: Thanks! Could you name the text by Vito Volterra?

Comment: The first place to look is chapter I, section II, §1 pp. 22-24 of the standard text Volterra, Vito, *Theory of functionals and of integral and integro-differential equations*. Dover edition with a preface by Griffith C. Evans, a biography of Vito Volterra and a bibliography of his published works by Sir Edmund Whittaker. Unabridged republ. of the first English transl, New York: Dover Publications, Inc. pp. 39+XVI+226 (1959), [MR0100765](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0100765), [ZBL0086.10402](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0086.10402).

Comment: You can also have a look at this [Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives/349584#349584): the unifying concept is the "Functional derivative" one, but since Volterra had in mind the functionals commonly used in the calculus of variation, his definition of functional derivative was a bit involved so, even if you are studying problems derived from, say, modern nonlinear system theory, is better to have a look at the good old sources.